# Lost the ability to post to usenet with pan newsreader since 18.04. How can I fix it?

Tags: 20.04, email

Since Focal Fossa update I am unable to post text or articles to usenet newsgroups using the pan newsreader. When I request to send the post it opens a dialog box with the message:

> There were errors with this post.
> Error:Bad email address.

I get this message whether I include an email address or leave it blank.

Anyone have a fix or work around?

Comment: pan support, unofficial is here

pan-users@nongnu.org

and maybe check your news server and posting profile email in pan settings .

Comment: I too have this problem with Mint System: Kernel: 5.4.0-54-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 tk: Gtk 3.24.13 wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal I can post using Thunderbird though